# Neovim Airline Powerline Fonts won't work

Tags: plugin-airline, font

I installed Airline status line for Neovim and put the following line in my init.vim:

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

I also followed the instructions for installing powerline symbols from [here](https://gist.github.com/demil133/4f16bd5bf7e6c68b2529)

As well as downloading the patched powerline fonts from [here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts/tree/master/samples),

But instead of the nice triangles on the status line all I get is rectangle placeholder symbols. I'm out of ideas for what else I need to do.

Comment: I assume you're using a terminal?  Did you set terminal to use the font?

Comment: Do'h. I did, but it was before some of the other steps I tried, and I forgot to set the font in the terminal again afterwards. Right after posting this question I discovered lightline which is much closer to what I want, so I'm dropping airline, but I will try that again to see if it works for the sake of completeness.

edit--that was it